# Use common edit/delete buttons in index page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I know how to create an index list of items and show an Edit / Delete / etc buttons for each row. I Have been searching for days for a way to use a single Edit / Delete / etc button for all rows.

Let me explain. I want to have a series of buttons on the right of my index page that would show my Edit, Delete. etc, buttons. I would then use a checkbox located a the front of each row to select the record I wish to edit/delete, etc. and pass this checked value to the button and to the controller.

Not sure if this makes sense.
[index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82nHA.png)

I want to eliminate the Duplicate, Edit and Delete buttons for each row and use the ones on the right.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, i would recomend using JQUERY to send ajax posts.
This has the looks of something I would do.

```
function deleteData() {
var id_delete = $('input[name="yourRadioButton"]:checked').val();
$.ajax({
    url: "{{route('routeUrlHere')}}",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {
        _token : "{{Session::token()}}",
        id_delete: id_delete
    }
})
.success(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    // Continue Jquery here

})
.error(function (xhr, status, response) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
});

}
```